# send file to email python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

There is a input form from which I can get docs(pdf, txt, png etc.) on page and send it to email. Everything works besides of one thing. I can select document only from a certain directory where all code locate and if I select my doc from another folder, I get error `No such file or directory`. How can I select doc from any folder?

[image]

`python:`

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def profile():
   file = request.form['file']
   password = "mypass"
   msg['From'] = "mymail"
   msg['To'] = "anothermail"
   msg['Subject'] = "Subject"
   msg = MIMEMultipart()
    
   file_to_send = MIMEApplication(open(file, 'rb').read())
   file_to_send.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=file)
   msg.attach(file_to_send)
    
   server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')
   server.starttls()
    
   server.login(msg['From'], password)
   server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
return render_template('profile.html', file=file)
```

`profile.html:`

```
<input type='file' class="form-control" name="file" id="uploadPDF">
<button class="btn btn-primary send">
  Send
</button>
```

Comment: Can you post the actual traceback you're seeing?

Comment: @KenKinder, sure. Please check it again. It happens, when I select image of other doc from another folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are at least a few problems. For one. you're looking for the uploaded file whether it's a POST or not. For another, the files would be uploaded to `request.files`, not `request.form`.

You might take a look at the Flask docs on [uploading files](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/). I think you want something like this:

```py
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def profile():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = "mymail"
        msg['To'] = "anothermail"
        msg['Subject'] = "Subject"

        file_to_send = MIMEApplication(file.stream.read())
        file_to_send.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=file.filename)
        msg.attach(file_to_send)

        messagge_content = msg.as_string()

        # (Your code that sends an email)

    return render_template('profile.html')
```

Remember also that your form needs to upload with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`:

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type='file' class="form-control" name="file" id="uploadPDF">
<button class="btn btn-primary send">
  Send
</button>
</form>
```